# BI 4.1 Web Intelligence and Universe test connection getting following error: CS: COM Provider CLSID not specified or erroneous

Tags: business-objects

BusinessObjects 4.1 Universe Designer and I am attempting to test a connection on a new development server and I am getting the following error:

**CS: COM Provider CLSID not specified or erroneous**

In Web Intelligence, when refreshing a report, it adds additional text:

**For information about this error, please refer to SAP Knowledge Base Article 2054721 on the SAP Support Portal. (IES 10901)(WIS 10901)**

I couldn't get useful information out of that article.

I am attempting to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database.  I am also getting this error when attempting to run Web Intelligence reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by installing the **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client** on the server that I installed BusinessObjects 4.1 on.

I am assuming that you will need to do this for the nodes that are running web intelligence and the machine you are using the Universe Designer on although I have not vetted this completely.

You will probably also need the correct version of the Native Client if you are connecting to an earlier or later version of SQL.